# Creating a line break within vCard format

Tags: ios, objective-c, line-breaks, vcf-vcard

I am creating a vCard and among other things am including a note, like so

```
[vCardArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NOTE:%@", note]];
```

Then, as is standard procedure, creating a string from the array using "\n", like so

```
NSString *string = [vCardArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

The conflict arising is that my note string has a "\n" in it, which messes up the vCard representation. I have tried using "\r" both as the separator and within my note string, but to no avail.

Is there a way around this? I'd like to add a line of extra space in my note. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the \n mess up the vCard representation? Is it not the case that some entries are allowed newlines in their content, NOTE being one of them? What is it you want to see as the exact output given a particular input?

Comment: In my above string called "note," I'd like to have it say "abcdef \nxyz". That note gets added into the vCardArray as "NOTE:abcdef \nxyz". The last line joins the objects in the array by \n, which is standard procedure from what I've read. If I remove \n inside of my note string, "abcdef xyz", the vCard works perfectly. But it's reading the \n inside of that string when it is joining the array at the end

Comment: Ok, so you want to see \n as text and not a newline, replace \n in the note text with \\n. [note stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"]. You can later do the reverse to put proper \ns back in.

Comment: Hi Rory, if I send the vCard using the \\n format to an Android user, the note looks like this abcdef \nxyz (when the input was abcdef \\nxyz). Is there any way around this?

Comment: What you see is what you coded. \\n means use the character \ then n. Otherwise a newline character is inserted. What did you want to show: \\n in text or it take a new line or something else?

Comment: I want the output to be a sentence, followed by a new line, followed by another sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines are represented as `\n` in vCard property values (as in: a backslash character, followed by an `n` character).  So, you would have to replace all newlines characters with `\n` before assigning the string to the NOTE property.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
NOTE:Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3
END:VCARD
```

Comment: as in [vCardArray addObject: NOTE: Line 1] then [vCardArray addObject:\n] then [vCardArray addObject: Line 2], etc?

Comment: I don't know Objective-C, so I don't know how you'd output a backslash character.  Just make sure it's outputting a `\ ` followed by a `n` and NOT an actual newline character.